# Compute Expectation and Variance of number of upper records

Tags: distributions, variance, expected-value

I should solve the following:

*Let $X_i,...,X_n$ be independent random variables such that for any i, j, i$\neq$j: $P(X_i=X_j) = 0$. Then, $X_i$ is an upper record iff $X_i > \max$ {$X_1,X_2,...,X_{i-1}$}.*

*So, $R_n = Y_1 + Y_2 + ... Y_n$ denotes the number of upper records in a sequence, here Y_i = (i) 1 if $X_i$ is a upper record and (ii) 0 otherwise (Indicator-Function).*

*Tasks:*

1. *Compute $E(R_n)$ and the limit of $E(R_n)$. Interpret the last limit result. How looks the probability space for this setup?*
2. *What is the variance $V(R_n)$ of the total number of upper records $R_n$?*

**EDIT** after comments of *jbowman*:

@1:

$P(X_i = \text{record})$ = ?

By permutations: In a sequence of n values $X_1,...,X_n$ there are n! permutations (= ways, to mix them). If $X_n$ = max, then there are (n-1)! permutations for the remaining $X_1,...,X_{n-1}$.

Probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P$) for $R_n$:

$\bullet$ $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,...\} = \mathbb N_{>0}$ ($0$ not included because $X_1$ is always a record and therefore $Y_1$ = $1$)

$\bullet$ $\mathcal F = P(\mathbb N_{>0}) ~ \mathrm{(Powerset ~with~ 2^{N_{>0}} ~possibilities)}$

$\bullet$ $\mu=\Sigma^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{i}$ ?

$E(R_n) = E(\Sigma^{n}_{i = 1} Y_i) = E(\Sigma^{n}_{i=1} \mathcal I_{x_i = record}) = \Sigma^{n}_{i = 1}E(\mathcal I_{x_i = \text{record}}) = \Sigma^{n}_{i = 1} \frac{1}{i} $

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \Sigma^{n}_{i = 1}1 \over i = \infty$ (harmonic series)

Interpretation of limes: The expectation exists, but is infinite, so one could argue, that's because we do not know how many records we will have in the future. Further we have learnt, that an absolute convergence is enough for an expectation, meaning, the expectation can still be infinite, but existing.

@2:

$\operatorname{Var}(R_n) = \operatorname{Var}(\Sigma^{n}_{i=1} Y_i) = \operatorname{Var}(\Sigma^{n}_{i=1} \mathcal I_{x_i = \text{record}}) = \Sigma^{n}_{i=1} \operatorname{Var}(\mathcal I_{x_i = \text{record}}) = \Sigma^{n}_{i=1} \left(\frac{1}{n} \times\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = \Sigma^{n}_{i=1}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$

Comment: Note that in the "First I tried..." part there is no need for the probabilities to sum to one.  $Y_1 = 1$ by construction, and the probability that $X_2 > X_1$ is $1/2$, so you are already at 1.5.  The reason why is because they are probabilities of *different* events, namely, $X_2 > X_1$, $X_3 > X_2,X_1$, etc.  Once you realize that, your path forward may be clearer.

Comment: @jbowman: Thanks for your comment!! But I think it's meant in another way. Here is how I see it: $Y_1$ stands for the first term of the sum $R_n$. It's not a probability, it's the result of the Indicator-Function. When $X_i$ is an upper record it adds a 1 to the sum of records. The probability function that I'm trying to find should assign every $Y_i$ the probability to turn 1. That is when $X_i$ is a record and therefore $\frac{1}{n×(n-1)}$. So that's why I think the probabilities should sum up to 1?

Comment: Does my explanation make a difference for you?

Comment: But maybe I'm now sensing what you meant: Since the first record is always a record, the probability for $Y_1$ is already 1 for $Y_1$=1? Is that what you thought of?

Comment: The probability that $X_n$ is a record is $1/n$, not $1/(n \times (n-1))$.  Why do you think it is the latter?  It is possible that each of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is a record, so you can have $n$ records for which the probability is $1 \times 1/2 \times 1/3 \dots = 1/n!$, the number of permutations of the observations; only one of the permutations has each observation being a record, so the probability *should* be $1/n!$.

Comment: The probabilities should sum to one only if exactly one of the $Y_i$ will equal $1$.

Comment: @ jbowman: thanks for your help, I edited my solution. Is this a valid solution now? I'm not quite sure about the probability space?

Comment: I'm not sure about that space, either: it looks unnecessarily large.  There is a *minimal* space: it's the one generated by the sequence of random variables $R_1, R_2, R_3, \ldots,.$  That might be worth a clear characterization.

Comment: Yes, it is, but your probability space needs work, as @whuber points out.